# Lowercase and split input python 3.x

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am trying to get an input() to be both lowercase and split (into separate words) and here is what I have:

```
commandSplit = input.split()
str.join(commandSplit)
str.lower(commandSplit)
```

However, I receive the error:

> TypeError: descriptor 'join' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'

Can anyone explain what the error is and how to resolve it?

Comment: `str.join` is a method of strings.  You have to call it from the string you want to use to join the other strings.  To join them with a comma, you would do `','.join(commandSplit)`

Comment: interchange the order of what you're trying to do: `'FOO BAR BAZ'.lower().split()` You don't need `str.join` if you're trying to split those words up (makes no sense).

Comment: #coldspeed : you answered the question, why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh `str.join` can still be used by itself as unbounded method, `str.join(", ", ["a", "b", "c"])` will work just fine

Answer (score 2):

The way I would get both lowercase and split for a string is using list comprehension.

```
mystr = 'This is Jamie Brinegar the novice Python programmer"
[word.lower() for word in mystr.split()]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to understand.

First, as explained by @Patrick, your usage of `str.join` is incorrect. The examples you copied from intended for `str` to be a string variable containing the delimiter you want to use to join a list of strings, i.e.

```py
', '.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

In your code above, it is unclear what the value of `str` is.

Second, `str.lower()` has a similar usage: in the examples you followed, `str` is intended to indicate the string you want to convert to lower-case. For example:

```py
"A String".lower() == "a string"
```

Finally, as to how to solve the problem at hand, the other answers give great strategies. Essentially, convert you string to lower-case first, then split it:

```py
input = 'Some User Input'
words = input.lower().split()
# => ['some','user','input']
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you want to use the form variable.method()

I believe what you want could be done like this

```
commandSplit = input().split()
commandSplit = [x.lower() for x in commandSplit]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var = input("Enter the line\n")
word_list = var.split(' ')
word_list = [str(word).lower() for word in word_list]
print(' '.join(word_list))
```

The output of split function is a list type.
To use join function the format is ".join(sequence_data type)"
With the above code:

Input:

```
 String Split And Join
```

Output:

```
 string split and join
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers offered good alternative solutions, I'd like to point out the reason you get

> TypeError: descriptor 'join' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'

is because you are using an unbounded method of class `str` (string) without an instance as first parameter. Python permits such usage; therefore, the following 2 lines yield the same result.

```
str.join(", ", ["a", "b", "c"])
", ".join(["a", "b", "c"])
```